# Reading a line partially from a file

Tags: python

I have a file in which data is stored in 4 columns such as:

```
MOORE 0.312 5.312 9
```

Now I just want to read the name from the line and store in a list, but i am not able to figure out how to do it.

Comment: it is a common question of reading lines and parsing strings, I advice you to search better...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
text = open('file.txt').readlines()

for line in text:
    print line.split(' ')[0]
```

Answer (score -1):

Not Python, but it won't get any easier.

```
$ cut -d" " -f 1 < file.txt
```